# Click name from one mysql table to show report from another table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a table with the following fields:
email - name - username - userid
currently the data in this table is pulled into a html table.

In a seperate table i have all the user's data / information.

What i would like to do is click on a name from the first table (consisting of email - name - username)

And have that users information shown on its own like a report generation.

Both the tables have the same unique userid's applied so could someone enlighten me as to the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the name with an anchor tag that has the id as some parameter.

I'd do it with 2 templates where one lists all the users (userList.php) and the other one shows detailed information about a user (userInformation.php).

userList.php:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <a href="userInformation.php?id=<?php echo $user->id;?>">
                <?php echo $user->username;?>
            </a>
        </th>
        <td><?php echo $user->email;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->propN;?></td>
    </tr>
    ...
    ...
</table>
```

userInformation.php:

```
<?php
    $userId = $_POST['id'];
    $user = someFunctionForGettingTheUserPerhaps($userId);
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $user->username;?></th>
        <td><?php echo $user->email;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->password;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->propN;?></td>
        ...
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: Replaced '.' with '->' since the latter is the property accessor notation in PHP.

Comment: Replace `$user.username` with `$user->username` etc. a period in php is the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

Set the onclick attribute of each table row to

```
echo('<tr onclick="location.href=\'userdet.php?id='.$row['userid'].'\'">
```

Where userdet.php is a page that puts the information you want into a HTML table.

*edit*

You could also try putting the data in like this http://www.jsfiddle.net/dduncan/UuA9E/
although that could get slow if you have a massive users table. (click the table row)